# How to create a maven build with junit-jupiter and junit-vintage profile

Tags: junit, junit4, junit5

I am trying to set up a maven build with two build profiles

- one with junit-jupiter (JUnit 5)
- one with junit-vintage (Junit 4)

The default profile is using the junit-jupiter-engigne and is working as expected, but the vintage profile (which are using the unit-vintage-engine) will not discover any tests...

The default profile, just run maven: `mvn test`
The vintage profile, run maven with property: `mvn test -Dtest=vintage`

Can anyone see what is wrong with the configuration in this simple project which only contains one class and two junit tests (one junit-jupiter and one junit (v 4.13.1)
https://github.com/jactor-rises/junit-profiles

***Note!***
The main branch do not contain any code.
There are two implementations, see branches: `feature/java` and `feature/kotlin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use property with the name "test" with `maven-surefire-plugin` for activating the profile because [it's predefined for running a single test](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html).

Rename it to something else.

Also, you can use `-P` instead: `mvn test -P vintage`.

Comment: aahhh... thanx! I new it had to be some overlooked detail of some kind...